# django: how to put a static file under root directory?

Tags: django

I am connecting to a SNS website and the website requires me to put a file at the root directory of the domain, such as http://www.a.com/test.txt and it will fetch it automatically to verify I am the owner of the domain.

I am using django and all the static files are under http://www.a.com/static/, how can I write the URL file to specify a file test.txt so that when the robot of the SNS website fetch the URL http://www.a.com/test.txt, it will correctly fetch the file I uploaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running apache, set up an alias in apache's httpd.conf:

```
#Alias /test.txt /filesystem/path/to/test.txt
```

Comment: Make sure you included the alias module in httpd.conf:

At the top add:
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason why it has to be an actual physical file. You could just as easily return whatever magic text is required via a view, mapped to the relevant URL:

```
url(r'^test\.txt', 'test_view')


def test_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("My magic text here", mimetype='text/plain')
```

Comment: A reason would be not wanting to load a complete application stack for something so simple.

Comment: @webjunkie You don't load the "complete application stack" per request in Django. Django runs as a separate set of processes, managed and despatched to by WSGI.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in production, just run

```
python3 manage.py collectstatics
```

it will automatically fetch the static file and add it in the desired path.